# Properly disposing a stream in F#

Tags: io, f#, idisposable

The following code throws an ObjectDisposedException when reading from a file.  It seems that the BinaryReader is going out of scope before the whole sequence is enumerated.  What is the right way to make this call safely without leaking the reader?  I prefer not to have to do stream management in the top-level code- ideally that is hidden away given a file path.

In this code, Edge.ReadBinary does the obvious task of deserializing an Edge from a binary stream.  In my code the folder does something more complex but I've simplified it here just for readability.

```
let rec readEdges (br:BinaryReader) =
    seq {
        match Edge.ReadBinary br with
        | None -> yield! Seq.empty  
        | Some(e) -> yield e; yield! readEdges br        
    }

let readBinaryEdges fn =
    use br=new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(fn))
    readEdges br

let sampled=readBinaryEdges fn |> Seq.fold (fun result l -> l::result) list.Empty
```

Comment: Evaluate the sequence eagerly, e.g. turn it into a `list` or `array` before returning it. Alternative, put the `use` directly inside the sequence expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in iljdarn's comment, putting `use` inside of a sequence expression fixes this. This works because the sequence expression builder defines its own semantics for the `use` keyword, to support disposal at the appropriate time. Thus, if you change the function to

```
let readBinaryEdges fn =
    seq { use br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(fn))
          yield! readEdges br }
```

the reader will be disposed with the sequence.